# Input/Output blank space

Tags: java, input, output

In this code, I get all words from a file and count them. After, that write them and their frequencies in a file.

This code is doing what i want exactly but additionally it count all blank spaces and write them to file , too. How can i not include them?

```
            String line;

            BigDecimal count = new BigDecimal(0);

            ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                String string1 = line.toLowerCase();

                String string[] = pattern.split(string1);
                for (String s : string) {
                    words.add(s);
                }
            }
            Map<String, BigDecimal> map = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();

            for (String s : words) {
                BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal(1);
                if (map.containsKey(s)) { 
                    count = map.get(s);
                    map.put(s, count.add(x));
                } else if (!map.containsKey(s)) {
                    map.put(s, x);

                }
            }

            Map<String, BigDecimal> wordHistogram = map;

            List<Entry<String, BigDecimal>> sortedWordHistogram = new LinkedList<Entry<String, BigDecimal>>(
                    wordHistogram.entrySet());
            Collections.sort(sortedWordHistogram, (o1, o2) -> o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue()));


            Map<String, BigDecimal> inTxt = map;

            for (Entry<String, BigDecimal> entry : sortedWordHistogram) {
                inTxt.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                writer.write(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
            }
```

I believe it is efficient enough but any adjustment to make it better or more efficient is pleased.

Comment: All the code was removed in an edit, which made an existing answer difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Simply replace your regex (`[^a-zA-Z]`) with `\\s+`.

This will make sure all the spaces between the words are considered while splitting a line.

Also, you can simplify your code further by replacing the following lines:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

    String string1 = line.toLowerCase();

    String string[] = pattern.split(string1);
    for (String s : string) {
        words.add(s);
    }
}
```

with

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    String string[] = line.trim().toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
    for (String s : string) {
        words.add(s);
    }
}
```

Note that I have also used `trim()` additionally in order to remove the leading and trailing whitespace characters from the line before splitting it.